# Getting GET in django view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this URL pattern to get to my view:

```
url(r'^api/cabinet/(?P<cabinetid>[0-9]+)/bin/$', views.api_cabinetbin),
```

and pointing my browser to `http://domain/api/cabinet/10/bin/` gives me the info on cabinet 10.

I would like to put some extra info to the URL, like this: `http://domain/api/cabinet/10/bin/?format=test`. However, this gives me a 404 (`{"detail":Not found."}` is the message I see in my browser).

The view is like this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,BasicAuthentication,TokenAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api_cabinetbin(request, cabinetid):
    ...
```

Comment: @Sayse it is not a duplicate of that question. I want to read the GET parameters in my `views.api_cabinetbin` function. But when I add those GET params, the entire routing breaks.

Comment: @Sayse yes, I want to call `http://domain/api/cabinet/10/bin/?info=extra` and use the `info` variable to do something in my view.

Comment: Just don't add the parameters to your url pattern and you should be fine. Leave the url pattern as is, and get your parameters in your `api_cabinetbin` view function with `request.GET`.

Comment: What is in the view? You appear to be looking for a key called "detail" but then passing in "info"

Comment: @Sayse, actually, I want to export the found data to Excel, but avoid using Ajax. Without it, it renders as HTML in my browser.

Comment: @elethan, well, and the point is, that that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please show what it is that you're trying to do in the view? it should work..

Comment: @Sayse I thought so, but it doesn't even get to the view.

Comment: Naively, I'm wondering if it is your API/view that is raising the 404, and the served answer looks like an ill-formed json. Review your ```api_cabinetbin``` (maybe post it here if you can strip the details) and look for what could go wrong.

Comment: @giant_teapot the first line in my view is a log line, which doesn't appear. I reckon django-rest-framework generates the 404.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, `format` has some magical properties in Django REST framework.

Using another variable did work.